# replace previous print output with new print output or add characters to previous output

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python programming, and I'm attempting to create a simple little game with a little "initialization" on boot up.

I pretty much want it to spell out "Welcome", but with all of the letters popping up every **100ms**.

I've got the `sleep` function down pat, however, rather than adding on each character to the end of the previous line, it is simply printing it all out on a new line.

This is what I'm currently getting:

```
W
e
l
c
o
m
e
.
```

I'd prefer it to just be `Welcome.`

This is my current code:

```
print("W")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("e")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("l")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("c")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("o")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("m")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("e")
```

I have looked around, but have failed to understand how to implement the function into Python. So an explanation would be extremely appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `end=''` when calling `print()`:

```
import time
for c in "Welcome":
    print(c, end='')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's `print()` function normally prints outputs on a new line, meaning that every time you print something, it appears on another line. To print everything on the same line, as you're asking, use the `print()` function like this:

```
print("W", end="")
```

Notice the second argument which tells Python to continue printing on the same line. The `print()` function defaults to an ending of `\n`, or new line. Setting `end` equal to "" replaced the `\n` with an empty string.

In the event that you need to use the `print()` function after you print out "Welcome", the last `print()` function you use to print out the 'e' should be normal, like this:

```
print("e")
```

This way if you print anything after "Welcome", it will print on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

How about this -

```
for c in "Welcome":
    print '\b%s' % c,
    time.sleep(0.1)
```